# build all maven dependencies at once

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a maven projects that includes multiple other maven projects. I am not very familiar with maven, I just use it to import jars and create executables.
What I would like to achieve is to build all maven projects that are on my computer when I build the project that include them.
For example there is project A that depends on projects B & C
Project's A pom

```
<dependency>
  project B
</dependency>
<dependency>
  project C
</dependency>
```

If there is some change on either of the dependencies (for example project B) I have to build project B and then project A. That is a pain some times and most of them I forget to do so, causing me to go back and build everything from scratch.

Is there any way to automate this? To be honest I tried searching for this online, but all I could get where information on how to build projects that include the dependencies, which is not what I want.
Thanks.

Comment: Do the projects belong together? In that case, you could use a multi-module project.

Comment: They done belong together, they are separated projects. how could I "put them together"? I will search for "multi-module project", is that it? Could I still be using each sub-project separately?

Comment: You have a parent project that contains multiple modules. Each module is a project that can inherit configuration from the parent project. When you build the parent project, all subproject will also be built.

Comment: You can structure your projects as maven multimodule project in which one project would be parent project without any source code and other projects like projects A,  B and C as submodules in your case. The intention behind this kind of structure is that the parent pom contains the common configurations that can be used by its sub modules to get rid of duplication and also contains the submoduls entries under <modules> tag those are build in one shot when you build parent pom. And of course answer of your question,  you can still use your projects separately.